# Проектирование БД для системы анкетирования

Tags: sql, база-данных

Всем привет. Имеется база данных с анкетами. Анкеты на данный момент есть 2 типов, структура анкет совершенно разная и в будущем возможно добавление новых анкет с новой структурой. Вопрос в том, как организовать связь между самой анкетой и опросником с вопросами. Сейчас имеется только такой вариант:

User

- Id
- Name

Questionnaire

- Id
- UserId
- Name
- QuizType // Тип анкеты, из расчета дальнейшего программного определения таблицы из которой подхватывать данные для формирования опроса
- QuizTypeAId // Ключ к таблице первого типа
- QuizTypeBId // Ключ к таблице второго типа

QuizTypeA

- Id
- //other data

QuizTypeB

- Id
- //other data

Хотелось бы увидеть ваши предложения/комментарии по проектированию такой БД.

Comment: @paxiyid, уточните, пожалуйста, вы проектируете БД, но не указали, как и какие данные вы собираетесь получать. Т.е., например, если у вас не будет никаких выборок, кроме `select * from Questionnaire join User`, то подойдет любая структура, вплоть до блоба с сериализованным описанием для каждой анкеты. По крайней мере комментарий `other data` говорит о том, что субд тут особо ни при чем.

Comment: Распишите, что вам надо, по вашей структуре это не ясно.

Вообще - общую инфу по анкетам можно хранить в одной табличке (название/описание/тип/и т.д.), а специфичные данные для каждой анкеты уже можно разнести по разным таблицам (либо хранить там же в JSON).

В анкете пользователя тогда надо хранить ссылку на общую таблицу (при этом можно убрать тип ссылки), т.е. отпадает необходимость в куче QuizTypeXId.

В специфичных для анкеты таблицах указывать ID опросника и по нему join`ить с общей таблицей.

Но что-то конкретное можно сказать, только узнав, что именно вам требуется.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, проблема как раз таки в том, что мне необходимо будет делать сложные выборки, в которых одним join не обойдется, да и какой смысл в бд, если данные сериализовать в лоб. Там, где указано "other data" будут поля, которые имеют смысл только для данной анкеты, а также ссылки на таблицы с вопросами. То есть сейчас проектируется база для создания этих самых анкет, в дальнейшем нужно будет связать наши анкеты так же с таблицей с вопросами, в которой встретятся такие же проблемы.

Comment: @BOPOH, для начала посмотрите мой предыдущий комментарий.
Теперь на счет множественных QuizTypeXId. Да, это я действительно не учел, конечно же в таблицах типа QuizTypeХ необходимо хранить ссылку на Questionnaire. Но меня беспокоит неопределенность в том что придется программно контролировать к какой таблице обращаться по QuizType, что вызовет трудности при добавлении нового типа анкет.

Я хотел сконцентрировать внимание на проблеме, а не на задаче, поэтому описал предметную область без каких либо уточнений.

Хотелось бы, что б вы понимали что мне нужно масштабируемое решение.

Comment: @paxiyid, открою вам маленький секрет - если данные нужны только для одного, то оптимальной будет одна структра, если для другого - то надо использовать другую структуру. Т.е. рассматривать задачу в отрыве от остального - смысла мало.

Возможно, даже правильный вариант окажется не таким удобным как "плохой"

Конечно, всего не предусмотришь, но ведь вы уже сейчас знаете что и как вам надо будет - значит это надо учитывать уже сейчас, а не потом.

Поэтому и надо сначала забить на структуру, т.е. определить что (и как) вам требуется, а уже потом под это проектировать схему.

Comment: @BOPOH, дело в том, что такую проблему я встречаю не в первый раз, и хотелось бы как раз таки найти правильное решение, хоть оно будет не таким и удобным.

Comment: @paxiyid, еще раз - вы сначала опишите, что вам требуется. "Разные анкеты" - это не предметная область, это галактика (если не больше).

Что такое "разные"? Просто разные вопросы в анкетах? Или это то, что я выше описывал (в одном вопросы по порядку, в другом - зависят от ответов)? Или что-то еще?

По приведенной структуре чувство такое, что это просто логирование - не надо отображать вопросы с вариантами ответом, достаточно просто сохранить номер_вопроса-ответ.

Опишите, что вы хотите, без структуры БД, только то, что должна делать программа. А там уже видно будет, чем можно помочь.

Comment: @BOPOH, окей, распишу поподробнее. У нас есть список анкет, пользователи в зависимости от ролей могут заполнять/смотреть результаты/создавать анкеты. Каждая анкета имеет определенный тип, от типа зависит какая-то информация, которая для каждого типа анкеты будет разной (типы могут появляться новые). Далее в каждой анкете есть вопросы, эти вопросы также делятся на разные типы (и также новые типы могут появляться), например, в одном вопросе нужно выбрать какой-то вариант и представленных, в другом написать комментарий, в третьем нужно будет еще что, допустим, оценить по шкале 100%.

Comment: @BOPOH, Соответственно необходимо будет иметь возможность создавать анкеты/проходить анкеты/смотреть отчеты по пройденным анкетам. Что-то около этого.

Comment: @paxiyid, про проблемы ничего не понятно, но ведь вопрос не о них... Ну, мне такая структура не нравится. Смысла в Questionnaire нет. Перенести оттуда Name и UserId в QuizTypeA, QuizTypeB... Запросы все равно придется формировать в коде в зависимости от того какие анкеты и как вы будете обрабатывать. Больше тут советовать что-либо сложно.

Comment: @paxiyid, есть у реляционных БД такая проблема, как работа с динамически изменяющимися структурами. Если есть какой-то параметр, который не может быть однозначно описан, то можно забыть о приведении БД к нормальным формам. В данном случае я бы нарушил НФ и создал две промежуточные таблицы для этого: 

1. ссылка_на_анкету {id юзера, id типа анкеты, id самой анкеты в таблице}  
2. отображение_типов_анкет_на_таблицы {id типа анкеты, имя таблицы }

В данном случае хранение имени таблицы в поле является нарушение правила из 1НФ - Все столбцы являются обычными, но лучше я ничего не вижу.